# Trying to upload in chunks

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, https, multipartform-data

I am trying to accomplish a large file upload on a blackberry. I am succesfully able to upload a file but only if I read the file and upload it 1 byte at a time. For large files I think this is decreasing performance. I want to be able to read and write at something more 128 kb at a time. If i try to initialise my buffer to anything other than 1 then I never get a response back from the server after writing everything.

Any ideas why i can upload using only 1 byte at a time?

```
z.write(boundaryMessage.toString().getBytes());
DataInputStream fileIn = fc.openDataInputStream();
boolean isCancel = false;

byte[]b = new byte[1];
int num = 0;
int left = buffer;

while((fileIn.read(b)>-1))
{
  num += b.length;
  left = buffer - num * 1;
  Log.info(num + "WRITTEN");

  if (isCancel == true)
  {
    break;
  }

  z.write(b);
}
z.write(endBoundary.toString().getBytes());
```

Comment: Why are you using a DataInputStream?  Does this problem appear if you use openInputStream() and do the byte counting correctly, as suggested by some of the answers?

Comment: What device and OS do you use? Please also add the rest of the code you use, so it is shown how you open/handle/close the HttpConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most input streams aren't guaranteed to fill a buffer on every read. (`DataInputStream` has a special method for this, [readFully()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte%5B%5D%29), which will throw an `EOFException` if there aren't enough bytes left in the stream to fill the buffer.) And unless the file is a multiple of the buffer length, no stream will fill the buffer on the final read. So, you need to store the number of bytes read and use it during the write:

```
while(!isCancel)
{
  int n = fileIn.read(b);
  if (n < 0)
    break;
  num += n;
  Log.info(num + "WRITTEN");
  z.write(b, 0, n);
}
```

Comment: Hi erickson, just give that a try with no luck, the client/server just dont seem to finish the connection after writing all bytes as it does when i write a byte 1 at a time.

Comment: when i analyze wireshark using your code it seems only 9542 bytes are transfered when the file is 119kb.

Comment: Tried that loop also but hangs when i print the endboundary and try to open inputstream to read response, and 9542 bytes are in tcp conversation of wireshrk.

Comment: still struggling - cant understand why it will go through ok if i print the image bytes one a time but if i print them like 1024*8 then i dont get a response back from server.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in BlackBerry OS that appeared in OS 5.0, and persists in OS 6.0.  If you try using a multi-byte read before OS 5, it will work fine.  OS5 and later produce the behavior you have described.

You can also get around the problem by creating a secure connection, as the bug doesn't manifest itself for secure sockets, only plain sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop isn't correct. You should take care of the return value from read. It returns how many bytes that were actually read, and that isn't always the same as the buffer size.

Edit:
This is how you usually write loops that does what you want to do:

```
OutputStream z = null;  //Shouldn't be null
InputStream in = null;  //Shouldn't be null
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 32];
int len = 0;
while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
    z.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

Note that you might want to use buffered streams instead of unbuffered streams.

Comment: Tried that loop also but hangs when i print the endboundary and try to open inputstream to read response, and 9542 bytes are in tcp conversation of wireshrk